# How can I refresh my DataTables without refreshing fullpage?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using PHP, MySQL, DataTables and modal Bootstrap 3 to code an AJAX form, I've achieved loading data from my MySQL database but I can't see new data without refreshing the entire page. This is my code:

**color.php**

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    require_once '../../class/query_color.php';
    $objColor = new Color;
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../ico/icono.ico">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Administración de colores</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/dataTables.colVis.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dataTablesLanguage.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dataTables.colVis.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dataTables.fnReloadAjax.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="container">
        <?php
            $consulta = $objColor->select_color();
            include('modal_add_color.php');
        ?>
            <button type='button' href='#agregarColor' class="btn btn-success" data-toggle='modal' data-backdrop='static'>Nuevo</button>
            <br/>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" id="colores">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Color</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
<?php                       
                    while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
                        $id = $fila['idColor'];                     
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>";
                            include('modal_edit_color.php');
                                echo "<button type='button' href='#editarColor".$id."' id='".$id."' class='btn btn-default btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-backdrop='static'>".$fila['nomColor']."</button>";
                            echo "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
?>                                      
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>

        <script>
            $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
              $(this).find('input:eq(1)').focus();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**modal_add_color.php**

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        require_once '../../class/query_color.php';

        $nomColor = $_POST['nomColor'];

        $objColor = new Color;
        $objColor->alta_color($nomColor);
    }else{
?>
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../class/ajaxColor.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="agregarColor" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h2 class="modal-title">Agregar color</h2>
                        </div>
                        <form id="formularioAltaColor" name="formularioAltaColor" method='post' action="modal_add_color.php" onsubmit="altaColor(); return false">
                        <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <table class="modal-table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label>Color</label></td>
                                    <td><input type='text' name='nomColor' class="form-control focusedInput" onfocus="this.value = this.value;" maxlength="30" required></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">Guardar cambios</button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
<?php
    }
?>
```

**ajaxColor.php**

```
function altaColor(){
var dataString = $('#formularioAltaColor').serialize();
var table = $('#colores').DataTable();

$.ajax({
    url: 'modal_add_color.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(datos){  
        $('#agregarColor').modal('hide');  

        /*What can I code here to refresh my dataTable without refresh fullpage?*/ 
    }
})
return false;
```

}

**dataTablesLanguage.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#colores').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "sProcessing":    "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":    "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords":   "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable":    "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo":          "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty":     "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered":  "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix":   "",
        "sSearch":        "Buscar:",
        "sUrl":           "",
        "sInfoThousands": ",",
        "sLoadingRecords":"Cargando...",
            "paginate": {
                "sFirst":    "Primero",
                "sLast":     "Último",
                "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"


        },
            "aria": {
                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        },
        //"responsive": true,           
        "iDisplayLength": 50
    });
});
```

**query_color.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';

class Color{

    private $conn;

    function color(){
        $this->conn = new Connection;
    }

    function select_color(){
        $result = NULL;
        if($this->conn->connect() == true){
            $query = "SELECT idColor, nomColor FROM color ORDER BY nomColor ASC";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
        }
        $this->conn->disconnect();
        return $result;
    }

    function alta_color($campo){
        $resultado = NULL;
        if($this->conn->connect() == true){
            $query = "INSERT INTO color (nomColor) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($campo)."')";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
        }
        $this->conn->disconnect();
        return $result;
    }
    }
?>
```

And it works fine, it insert data without problem, but I want to omit the part of reloading the fullpage to see inserted data.

Comment: what if you use a ajax get after the post

Comment: Could you cite the code?

Comment: inside your `success:function()`callback you can add an `$.ajax({ url: fetchdata.php' type: "get",success: function(response){ echo data;}`
Inside fetchdata you will return the values in the database. then you use jquery to display the data on the frontend

Comment: Yeah, I actually tried, but I really don't know how to do it using datatables

Comment: this doesn't make sense.. why do you have your ajax call in a php file? and why are you doing ` include('modal_edit_color.php');` in every single iteration over the query results?

Comment: also, nowhere in your code do you ever call datatables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refresh datatables use the [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) function. For this to work however, you need to update the datatables data object.  For instance you can use the [`cell.data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29.data%28%29) function if you need to update the data in a single cell:

```
var table = $('#colores').DataTable();

$.ajax({
    url: 'modal_add_color.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(datos){  
        $('#agregarColor').modal('hide');
        cell = table.cell($('jquery-selector-here'));
        cell.data('new-cell-data-here');
        table.draw();
    }
})
```

Updating the table html directly is not advised as the new data will not be seen by datatables.  You need to update datatables through it's [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) and then redraw the table.

Comment: Using `draw(false)` lets you stay on the same page.

Comment: yes.. but since he didn't include any datatables code we really have no idea if he's even using paging or for that matter what his data source is - though it seems reasonable to assume he's using DOM based data.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include my dataTables.js file, I've done

Comment: so what's the problem with my answer?

Comment: I've tried adding `table.draw()` code but it doesn't work

Comment: what about the first bit `var table = $('#colores').DataTable( ...`

Comment: and did you update your table cell(s) via datatables API method as I mentioned?

Comment: Could you give me an example, I can't understand how to implement you mentioned

Comment: @AleexQuiiroz - I gave you a perfectly usable example in my answer.  If you can't figure things out from that i don't know what to tell you.  But it is the correct answer and it works.  If you are not going to accept it I guess I'm wasting my time trying to help.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, It just I'm newer using dataTables, my question is about `cell = table.cell($('jquery-selector-here'));
        cell.data('new-cell-data-here');` lines, because I don't know what selector should I use or what, I'm trying, Please, be patient with me

Comment: **(a)** there's no way to answer that question since I don't know what your data is or what you want to update.  **(b)** a question about how to update cell data in datatables is different than the one in your post.  I've answered the question you asked already.  If you have a new question you should open a new question.

Comment: You have the reason, I should open a new question, thank you a lot for your time, regards

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this with your data

```
var str='';
for(var value in datos){
 str+='<tr><td>'+value+'</label></td>';
}
$('tbody').html(str);
```